# React, al hacer un console.log de un json, éste aparece duplicadoen la consola

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch

Hola que talestoy aprendiendo a usar RapidAPI y manejarme con las APIS junto con React, y tengo un problema (que no es realmente grave, pero no sé por qué ocurre), en mi código app.js simplemente hago 1 console log, y hago la llamada a la api por medio de fetch.
En consola aparece el objeto duplicado. Si decido quitar uno de estos .then, la consola me marca que la promesa está en **{ pending }** pero sigue apareciendo este mensaje duplicado por consola. Y no sé por qué se duplica. El catch que también tiene un console.log que marcaría un mensaje de error si lo hubiera, no es la causa del problema, ya que al quitarlo, sigue apareciendo el objeto dos veces por consola.

Estoy corriendo la aplicación mediante React, con create-react-app e iniciando el puerto 3000 por defecto.

```
    function App() {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key': '41c6829c14msh391ac4155f3c9f0p12dee2jsn343752f89dfb',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'online-movie-database.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };
      
      fetch('https://online-movie-database.p.rapidapi.com/auto-complete?q=jumanji', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es exactamente el mismo objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe que ocurre lo agradecería. La api trata de dar información sobre películas cuando introduces un título, poco más.

Un saludo.

Comment: tenes que meter el fetch en un effect con dependencia vacia, para que ese efecto se ejecute unicamente cuando se monta el componente ``useEffect(() => {"aca la funcion fetch"}, [])``

Comment: Si tienes en tu index.js el modo estricto es normal ese comportamiento. No te alarmes, solo pasa en el modo de desarrollo. Cuando haces el build de producción ocurre solo una vez.

Comment: Pues sí que lo tengo no sabía que se debía a eso, gracias @JaimeMenéndez

Comment: De acuerdo gracias @AgustinG.

Comment: Si quieres más detalles échale un ojo a esta pregunta y sus respuestas https://stackoverflow.com/q/48846289/8838721. Si no sabes inglés puedes usar un traductor. Muy buena suerte.